# Paginating associated models with CakePHP 2.x

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, gallery

I’m developing gallery software using CakePHP 2 and have run into an issue when trying to paginate content.

I have two main models on the site, them being `Album` and `Image`. They are linked by a has many relation where an album can have many images, and each image belongs to one album. I can paginate album lists with no problem, using the following on my **AlbumsController.php** file:

```
public $paginate = array(
    'limit' => 21
);
```

And then, in the method I want to paginate (for example, `index`):

```
public function index() {
    $this->set('albums', $this->paginate());
}
```

I’m having problems paginating the album view. For the album view, the system is using the relationship to take all the images belonging to that album, using the following function:

```
public function view($id = null) {

        if (!$id) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Album not found.'));
        }

        $album = $this->Album->findById($id);

        if (!$album) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Album not found.'));
        }

    $this->set('album', $album);
}
```

However, I have no clue how to get the system to paginate the album view based on the images. I have tried using:

```
$this->set('albums', $this->paginate());
```

To no avail (the system seems to ignore it), while also tried overloading the `paginate()` function while only getting errors. So, can anyone point me out on the right direction for this? It’s a very simple relation I have here and I believe the answer is also likely a very simple one, but I can’t seem to find it and even here in Stack Overflow most of the related threads I’ve found ask about much more complicated systems with searches being made in relations. I don’t need any of that, this is a very simple pagination case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it done, finally. Here's what the function ended up looking like:

```
public function view($id = null){

    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Album not found.'));
    }

    $album = $this->Album->findById($id);

    if (!$album) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Album not found.'));
    }

    $this->paginate = array(
        'conditions'=>array(
            'Image.album_id'=>$id),
        'limit'     =>'21'
    );

    $album = $this->paginate('Image');

    $this->set('album', $album);
    $this -> set('id', $id);
}
```

So what I did was add a new set of constrains for the paginate array, and then force it to paginate images based on the album ID. This also had the collateral effect of forcing me to rewrite my album `view.ctp` file, since it completely changed the way data is received by the template. In this case, I had to stop using `foreach($album['Image'] as $image)` to go through the images, instead using a `while($image_no < 21)` loop to access each instance of `$album[number]['Image']`.

I'm sure there must be better/more elegant ways to attain what I needed, but since I couldn't find any other way I'm leaving this here for the record, in case anyone else runs into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

May be it will helpful for you:

```
class AlbumsController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Albums';

    var $paginate = array(
    'limit' => 95,
    'order' => array(
    'Album.name' => 'asc')
    );

    function index() {
            $this->Album->recursive = 0;
            $this->set('albums', $this->paginate());
            $this->set("title_for_layout","CakeGal");
    }

    function view($id = null) {
            if (!$id) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid album', true));
                    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            $this->set('album', $this->Album->read(null, $id));
            $this->set("title_for_layout", $this->Album->data['Album']['name']);
    }
```

}

Comment: @Tizzy’s use of throwing a `NotFoundException` is far more appropriate than your flash message-and-redirect for an invalid album ID.

Comment: Could you tell me where exactly is the view function being asked to paginate there? I can't seem to see it :\